# Как передать значение выпадающего списка в базу данных?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, post, запрос, список

Создаю форму для регистрации. В ней создал выпадающий список с двумя значениями на выбор: "x" и "y", - необходимо, чтобы любое из выбранных значений сохранялось в базе данных, в соответствующем поле (назовём его "z").

Для всей формы (куда также входят значения "login", "password", "phone", "email") заданы следующие параметры передачи данных обработчику:

```
<form id="login" class="login" action="save_user.php" method="post">
```

Код на странице, где пользователь выбирает значение из списка, выглядит следующим образом:

```
<h2>Выберите значение</h2>
<div class='selectBox'>
<select name=letter>
  <option value=yes>X</option>
  <option value=no>Y</option>
</select>
```

Код файла save_user.php выглядит следующим образом:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['login'])) { $login = $_POST['login']; if ($login == '') { unset($login);} }
if (isset($_POST['password'])) { $password=$_POST['password']; if ($password =='') { unset($password);} }
if (isset($_POST['phone'])) { $phone=$_POST['phone']; if ($phone =='') { unset($phone);} } 
if (isset($_POST['email'])) { $email=$_POST['email']; if ($email =='') { unset($email);} }

$letter= (isset($_REQUEST['letter'])) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['letter']) : '';

if (empty($login) or empty($password) or empty($phone) or empty($email))
{
exit ("Вы ввели не всю информацию, вернитесь назад и заполните все поля!");
}

$login = stripslashes($login);
$login = htmlspecialchars($login);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$password = htmlspecialchars($password);
$phone = stripslashes($phone);
$phone = htmlspecialchars($phone);
$email = stripslashes($email);
$email = htmlspecialchars($email);
$letter= stripslashes($letter);
$letter= htmlspecialchars($letter);

$login = trim($login);
$password = trim($password);
$phone = trim($phone);
$email = trim($email);
$letter= trim($letter);

include ("bd.php");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE login='$login'",$db);
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if (!empty($myrow['id'])) {
exit ("Извините, введённый вами логин уже зарегистрирован. Введите другой логин.");
}
```

Далее сохраняю все значения в базе данных:

```
$result2 = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO users (login,password,phone,email,letter) VALUES('$login','$password','$phone','$email','$letter')");
```

Также пробую сохранить значение "letter" следующим образом (заранее убрав его из предыдущего способа):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users SET `letter`='{$letter}'";
```

Ну и конец кода:

```
if ($result2=='TRUE')
{
echo "Вы успешно зарегистрированы! Теперь вы можете зайти на сайт. <a href='index.php'>Главная страница</a>";
}
else {
echo "Ошибка! Вы не зарегистрированы.";
}
?>
```

На выходе получается, что в базу данных добавляются все указанные значения, кроме значения "letter". Тип строки в базе данных для этого значения "VARCHAR", с длиной в 20 символов.
Так всё-таки каким образом добавить значение "letter" в соответствующую строку базы данных?

---

Пока разобрался со следующими строками:

```
<h2>Выберите значение</h2>
<div class='selectBox'>
<select name=letter>
<option value=yes>X</option>
<option value=no>Y</option>
</select>
```

Дело в том, что в базе данных, при нажатии кнопки "обзор", отображаются все столбцы таблицы (login, password, phone, email), а вот столбец "letter" не отображается, и введённое при выборе из списка значение можно посмотреть только тогда, когда в "параметрах строк" текущей таблицы нажимаешь кнопку "изменить". Оказывается, записываются именно значения option value - "yes" или "no", - то есть для записи самих значений надо заменить код на следующий:

```
<option value=X>X</option>
<option value=Y>Y</option>
```

Однако всё-равно не ясно, почему записанные значения нельзя посмотреть в "обзоре таблицы базы данных", - даже тогда, когда ставлю галочку "показать все столбцы", столбец "letter" отображается, но без названия, и со значением "null".
Есть какая-то подсказка, как его отобразить в базе данных, именно с выбранным значением?

Comment: Есть ошибки? Первый способ работает? Второй способ у вас ошибочный

Comment: Система ошибок не выдаёт, ни один из способов не работает.

Comment: копайте в сторону PDO http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php